# INFO: task init:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds in CentOS 5.6 after cron jobs editing

Tags: cron, boot, centos5

I have a VM and after editing cron jobs it hung.

When rebooting the VM it shows this message from the VMWare Sphere Console:

```
INFO: task init:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds
```

How to enter avoiding the cron jobs or how to edit them from this state?

P.S. Can't access physically the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into single user mode (https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html) and edit the crontab from there.

Comment: It doesn't work. The same message appears over and over: `INFO: task init:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds`. I think that's because the compromised task is `init`.

Comment: Then boot to a rescue ISO of Centos and edit it from there. However, if init can't start, I seriously doubt your issue is just related to a cron job